# Compute Engine Application SSH for server migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, server-migration

I am in the process of moving an application instance from Google Cloud to IONOS. I have taken an image, exported it to a Google Bucket in .vmdk format and imported it as a new image in IONOS to spin up an instance. This has all worked as expected and the application is accessible with all data. However I can not access the SSH as the keys / credentials are not in the image - how can I add the SSH keys to the image in Google Cloud so they transfer to the new server allowing me to access the root files etc?

Comment: The keys are located in `~/.ssh`. Check there in the restored image. `~` is the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [Managing SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys):

> An SSH key consists of the following files:
>
> - A public SSH key file that is applied to instance-level metadata or project-wide [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata).
> - A private SSH key file that the user stores on their local devices.

As it was mentioned by *@John Hanley*, on you local machine you can find SSH keys located at the following paths:

```
$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine – private key
$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub – public key
```

In addition, you're able to create your own SSH keys and add them to your instance:

1. create SSH keys:

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]

   - public key file: `~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME].pub`
   - private key file: `~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME]`
2. add public SSH key to your VM:

   - go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE`
   - paste the content of public key (cat `~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME].pub`) in ssh-keys text-area:

[image]

3. connect to VM instance:

   ```
   ssh -i [PATH_TO_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY] username@[EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE]
   ```